# How to add dynamic classes to looped elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a project where the page has multiple sections with `data-nav` attributes like below:

```
<section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue.</p>

        <p>Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt..</p>

        <p>Aliquam a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
```

my target is to create nav links dynamically using javascript that scrolls to the corresponding section and add classes to the active elements.
i used a for loop to loop through the sections and used the `textContent` of the `data-nav` attribute which holds the name of the section and create the nav links with it:

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('main > section');
const sectionArray = Array.from(sections);
for (let section of sectionArray.reverse() ){
    sectionNumber = section.dataset.nav;
    var navLink = document.createElement('li');
    var navAnchor = document.createElement('a');
    navLink.appendChild(navAnchor);
    navLink.setAttribute('class', 'menu__link');
    navAnchor.textContent = sectionNumber;
    navList.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', navLink);
};
```

for the scrolling part i used a for loop inside a click event listener to check which section is clicked and scroll to it:

```
navList.addEventListener('click', (evt)=>{
    sectionAnchor = evt.target.textContent;
    
    sectionArray.forEach(section => {
        if(sectionAnchor === section.dataset.nav){
            section.scrollIntoView();
        };
    });
});
```

Now I am stuck at how can I add active class dynamically to the navigation bar when it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add this to your code:

```
navList.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(el => { // it will select all the <a> element on the navList
  el.classList.remove('active'); // it will remove the active class from all of them
})
evt.target.classList.add("active") // it will add the active class just on the clicked <a> element
```

So it will be:

```
navList.addEventListener('click', (evt)=>{
    sectionAnchor = evt.target.textContent;

    navList.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(el => { 
      el.classList.remove('active'); 
    })
    evt.target.classList.add("active") 

    sectionArray.forEach(section => {
        if(sectionAnchor === section.dataset.nav){
            section.scrollIntoView();
        };
    });
});
```